# wxJSON output file rows ordered differently than intended

Tags: json

I am trying to use wxJSON, this is my simple test function containing example data in the correct form I need (unfortunately in my application order matters):

```
TEST(wxJSONTestGroup, wxJSON_Write_File_Test)
{
    wxFile file("AppWrData.json", wxFile::write_append);
    wxFileStream outStream("AppWrData.json");
    // construct the JSON value object and add values to it
    wxJSONValue root;

    root["MicroNet"]["Description"] = wxString("Application Data File");
    root["MicroNet"]["Version"]     = wxString("3.0.0");

    root["CONST TYPS xTyps"][0]["strFmt"]   = wxString("s8h");
    root["CONST TYPS xTyps"][0]["wTypSize"] = wxString("10");
    root["CONST TYPS xTyps"][0]["wNameIx"]  = wxString("0");

    root["CONST TYPS xTyps"][1]["strFmt"]   = wxString("s21s21");
    root["CONST TYPS xTyps"][1]["wTypSize"] = wxString("42");
    root["CONST TYPS xTyps"][1]["wNameIx"]  = wxString("1");

    root["CONST TYPS xTyps"][2]["strFmt"]   = wxString("s8");
    root["CONST TYPS xTyps"][2]["wTypSize"] = wxString("10");
    root["CONST TYPS xTyps"][2]["wNameIx"]  = wxString("2");

    // construct a JSON writer: use the default writer's settings
    // wxJSONWriter writer( wxJSONWRITER_STYLED, 0, 4);
    wxJSONWriter writer;
    writer.Write(root, outStream);  
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

this is the JSON output it makes:

```
{
    "CONST TYPS xTyps" : [
    {
        "wTypSize" : "10",
        "wNameIx" : "0",
        "strFmt" : "s8h"
    },
    {
        "wTypSize" : "42",
        "wNameIx" : "1",
        "strFmt" : "s21s21"
    },
    {
        "wTypSize" : "10",
        "wNameIx" : "2",
        "strFmt" : "s8"
    }
    ],
    "MicroNet" : {
        "Description" : "Application Data File",
        "Version" : "3.0.0"
    }
}
```

and this is the output I would like to have:

```
{
    "MicroNet" :
    {
        "Description": "Application Data File",
        "Version" : "3.0.0"
    },
    "CONST TYPS xTyps": [
    { 
        "strFmt": "s8h",    
        "wTypSize": "10", 
        "wNameIx": "0" 
    },
    { 
        "strFmt": "s21s21", 
        "wTypSize": "42", 
        "wNameIx": "1" 
    },
    { 
        "strFmt": "s8",     
        "wTypSize": "10", 
        "wNameIx": "2" 
    }
    ],
}
```

any idea about? Seems to me that the output is alphabetically ordered so I hope can be possible to disable the ouput order but I don't understand how to isable it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by myself. The container used by wxJSON is a stl::map or if stl is not available an equivalent map made in wxWidgets. So, the key order is undefined. The only order that is preserved is the order of the array slots.